# how to install apk from url and install programically

Tags: android

im creating a feature in my application to download new version of apk from server and install but im facing problem after so many resech i found this code below
when im debugging after this line `c.connect();`  is go on `catch()`  and print `Toast` message what is the problem please help me  my url is working u can try it on webbroser someone give me this online apk url

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Button  button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


   Update("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/245131571/SampleApp.apk");       



        }

    });



}





      public void Update(String apkurl){
          try {
                URL url = new URL(apkurl);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");

                c.connect();

 String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/naz/";
                File file = new File(PATH);
                file.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(file, "app.apk");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();//till here, it works fine - .apk is download to my sdcard in download file

                Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .setData(Uri.parse(PATH+"app.apk"))
                .setType("application/android.com.app");
                startActivity(promptInstall);//installation is not working

            } catch (IOException e) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         }  



}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.appinstall.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: Requesting the permission to install new packages sounds like a bad choice - a very bad. Most people will drop the app instantly the second they see that right requested. Is there any reason you can't just download the update using the default browser? It will still show a warning, but it won't require special rights for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: my code go on exception after this line    c.connect();

Comment: It's probably because you're not using an AsyncTask for downloading data.

Comment: then what will i do help me please

Comment: what should i do when apk url required authentication .

Answer (score 1):

Please find below a full working example using the above codes.
This answer is just to gather a full working example using the above permissions except

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

The Activity is as below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Update("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/245131571/SampleApp.apk");

            }

        });

    }

    public void Update(final String apkurl) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, String, String>() {
            String result="";
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(apkurl);
                    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url
                            .openConnection();
                    c.setRequestMethod("GET");

                    c.connect();

                    String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/download/";
                    File file = new File(PATH);
                    file.mkdirs();
                    File outputFile = new File(file, "app.apk");
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                    InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len1 = 0;
                    while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    }
                    fos.close();
                    is.close();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    result="Update error! "+ e.getMessage();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    
                }
                return result;
            }
            
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            };
            
        }.execute();

    }

}
```